# How do I use this package - xd-file?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I am trying to use this package to manipulate an Adobe XD file.

Link to the package: [xd-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xd-file)

I need to use this code snippet in a JavaScript file. I am using Node.js.

The method I need to use is readXDFile and the code snippet displayed in the Readme is:

```
(filePath: string) => Promise<{
  document: Object,
  interactions: Object,
  metadata: Object,
  resources: Object,
  artboards: Array<Object>,
}>
```

What is the Javascript equivalent for this typescript code?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Here's the JS code that I wrote now:

```
var xdFile = require("xd-file");

filePath = './test/Test-1/XD-Test-1.xd'
xdData = xdFile.readXDFile(filePath)
console.log(xdData)
```

And here's the output:

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

How do I get the Object as the output?

**RESOLVED**

Replaced `console.log(xdData)` with:

```
xdData.then(                                       
    function (value) { console.log(value) },
    function (error) { console.log(error) }
);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Base on what I understand it returns a promise, with that you should use what call `asyns/await`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I have updated the question with the solution!